# 'web_accessible_resources'. Parsing array failed at index 0: 'resources' is required Could not load manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm try to develop a chrome extension for my graduation project ,
when load the folder of my project to chrome://extensions/ , i got this error : Error at key 'web_accessible_resources'. Parsing array failed at index 0: 'resources' is required
Could not load manifest.

manifast.json :

```
{    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "test ",
    "version": "0.9",
    "description": "This extension notifies users if it encounters a potential phishing website or not .",
    "background.service_worker":
    {

        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
        "js": ["detectPhish.js"]
    }],
    "icons":
    {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{ 
    "matches": [
        "node_modules/gmail-js/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "jquery.js",
        "node_modules/gmail-js/src/gmail.js",
        "detectPhish.js",
        "main.js"
  ]
}]
   
}
```

Comment: Replace `matches` with `resources` inside web_accessible_resources and add `"matches":["<all_urls>"]` as shown in the documentation.